# Ubuntu 20.04 Text Not Displaying Properly

Tags: updates, fonts, 19.10, text, 20.04

I updated to Ubuntu 20.04 from 19.10.

Text doesn't display properly for system elements. Examples are shown below.

Is this a bug with 20.04? How can I fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe some package(s) got lost during upgrade. Try this terminal command: `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be some font issue. I guess some font got deleted after upgrading?

Went into Tweaks and blindly changed fonts to known fonts and things are all fixed.